How to make metabase read-only?
I have a metabase instance I'm migrating away from. It has both athena and rds database connections. How do I prevent users from editing existing cards and dashboards and creating new ones?

https://discourse.metabase.com/t/read-only-permission/23494/4 might be useful

If you are using collection you can set the collection level permission to user as view only. Please refer to this article Collection Permissions
If you want to set the permission on data level for user please check this article: Data level permission
You can also create a specific group from Admin settings and set it for view permission for a dashboard and add user to that group. It will allow user to only view the dashboard.
Read only permission
